# _CRT_DEBUGGER_HOOK fatal error

Tags: c++, windows, fatal-error

I have a the same problem described in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280477/crt-debugger-hook-throws-exception) in my c++ function which writes the values of several arrays into a file. In the following I brought the part of the code that does this.

```
double *VAR = new double[NumPts];
for( iArray = 0; iArray<nArrays; iArray++)
    for( iComp=0; iComp<nComponents; iComp++ )
    {                       
        for ( k=0; k<dims[2]; k++ )
        {       
            kOffset = k * dims[0] * dims[1];
            for ( j=0; j<dims[1]; j++ ) 
            {           
                jOffset = j * dims[0];
                for ( i=0; i<dims[0]; i++ ) 
                {               
                    id = i + jOffset + kOffset;
                    Values = sgrid->GetArray( iArray )->GetComponent( id, iComp );

                    VAR[ id] = Values;                                                                          
                }
            }
        }   

        INTEGER4 DIsDouble = 1;
        // Writing the array into the file.
        I = TECDAT112( &NumPts, &VAR[0], &DIsDouble );
    }        

// Close the file.
I = TECEND112();
```

I have 5 arrays stored in a class instance called, sgrid. Arrays are either three dimensional or one dimensional. The total number of components are 12. Each component can be retrieved by GetArray and GetComponent functions.The above code loops through all the components and writes their values to file by TECDAT112 function in a library. (I am also using Debug mode in VS2008 x64.)

It seems that the cause of my problem is a bit different and not because dependencies are not compiled in VS2008. Actually, the loop continues to work perfectly and the values of the components 1-9 are written successfully. The problem occurs when the code tries to write the values of component#10. From there, I get the error:

"Microsoft Visual Studio C Runtime Library has detected a fatal error"

and points me to the function _CRT_DEBUGGER_HOOK. To test this hypothesis that if there is a problem with the arrays and their components, I commented out the line that writes the values to the file and noticed that the loop successfully goes through all 12 components. Can the problem be because of memory issues?

Comment: Your curly brackets are unbalanced...

Comment: Use `std::vector<double>` instead of `double[]`. Also, have you considered the possibility that your code indeed contains an error and the library is simply doing its job and detecting it?

Comment: I am following the syntax of the function TECDAT112 which uses double[] instead of vector. I don't know what is causing the error. For sure, my code is missing something.

Comment: Create a `std::vector`. Use its `.reserve()` method to reserve enough space for `NumPts` elements, then use `VAR.at(id) = Values;` to write to it. You can still pass `&VAR[0]` to the function that expects `double[]`. The point is, `.at()` will throw an exception if you try to write to an array index out of bounds.